# MS Teams Bot to record meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

we are developing an AI Bot that can join MS Teams meetings and take notes, similar to fireflies.ai. We are having trouble understanding how this will work. Can anyone help us in mentioning some of MS Teams SDKs or documentations that can solve our problem. We want to approach this by giving meeting link to our Bot that joins the meeting and records it in background. This meeting should be saved to our servers. Later we can use our AI tools and perform operations on the recording.

We have looked into [PsiBot Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/PublicSamples/PsiBot) but we prefer using Nodejs to perform this action if possible or any other alternative. Is this the only solution or we can do something else.

Comment: To record the meeting, your bot can use the Real-time Media Platform to access real-time audio and video streams. However, Teams platform currently does not support direct recording of meetings. You would need to capture the audio and video streams in real-time and save them to your servers. You can find more information on the Real-time Media Platform here.-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/requirements-considerations-application-hosted-media-bots

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT The problem with this solution is that it would need an admin (or user) consent to work. fireflies.ai could record meetings without any consent.

Comment: yes exactly. are there any alternatives to PsiBot ?

Comment: any app that requires access to Teams meeting transcripts and recordings would need appropriate permissions. These permissions can be either organization-wide application permissions or resource-specific consent (RSC) application permissions.
For an app like fireflies.ai to record meetings, it would need to have the necessary permissions. If it uses organization-wide application permissions, the tenant administrator would need to authorize these permissions. This would allow the app to access transcripts and recordings for all meetings in the tenant.

Comment: In both cases, consent is required either from the tenant administrator (for organization-wide permissions) or from authorized users (for meeting-specific RSC permissions.
https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html
https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I just tried fireflies.ai two weeks ago and no permission was required. I didn't even use my Microsoft login. I authenticated to fireflies.ai with my Google account and it scanned my calendar for Teams meetings and the Fireflies bot joined my Teams meeting without any intervention. The bot was a guest user but after the meeting, I got a transcription from the meeting with user labels.

Comment: yes this is true. Fireflies joins teams meeting as a guest if it has meeting link. Meeting link can be given directly or from calenders. It seems like they are using scrapping tools/headless browser to open the link and join. But I don't want that approach since it can lead to problems everytime MS Teams interface changes.

Comment: How is MS Teams running on browser and reading streams. Can we replicate that ? anyone aware of any technologies that can do it ?

Comment: ok. We will check this with internal team and let you know the update once we have any.

Comment: Hi @Waleed did you guys manage to develop the bot?

Comment: No. we have currently paused the project. Will get back to it soon.